# Discord Bot Error: can't send non-None value to a just-started coroutine

Tags: python, discord, python-asyncio

I am new to Discord API.

I am trying to send messages to my discord channel using a bot. I would like to run the function "scheduled_run" so that it sends messages to the channel.

Below code should send "Remainder" to channel but I am receiving error "can't send non-None value to a just-started coroutine"

```
async def get_channel(id):
  return 

async def scheduled_run():
  channel = get_channel(83863944137526xxxx)
  await channel.send("Remainder")

if __name__ == "__main__":
  loop = get_event_loop()
  loop.run_until_complete(scheduled_run())
```

Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 83, in 
loop.run_until_complete(scheduled_run())
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
return future.result()
File "main.py", line 78, in scheduled_run
await channel.send(msg)
TypeError: can't send non-None value to a just-started coroutine

Is it possible to send bot message without user reply? Please correct my code

Comment: You're missing `await` in front of the call to `get_channel`. Since the coroutine object created by a call to an `async def` happens to have a method named `send` (completely unrelated to discord), the error is somewhat cryptic.

Answer (score 0):

You must fetch the channel directly from client:

```
channel = client.get_channel(83863944137526xxxx)
await channel.send("Remainder")
```

Comment: client.get_channel returns null. Please suggest an other way

Comment: what is your defined discord client or bot? it would be that `<name>.get_channel(83863944137526xxxx)`